# Extra data on socket communication in Julia

Tags: sockets, network-programming, julia

I'm working on getting a grip on socket programming in Julia, and I'm getting, what seems to me at least, a really weird bug. This is my testing program:

```
function startServer(port::Integer)
    server=listen(port)
    while true
        sock=accept(server)
        @async while true
            sig=read(sock,Int64)
            if sig==0
                write(sock,rand(Int64))
            elseif sig==1
                raw=read(sock,Int64)
                write(sock,raw+1)
            end
        end
    end
end

function dumbwrite(connection)
    while true
        kappa=read(connection,Int64)
        println(STDOUT,kappa)
    end
end

function roll(port::Integer)
    @spawn startServer(port)
    clientside=connect(port)
    @spawn dumbwrite(clientside)

    write(clientside,0)
    write(clientside,0)
    write(clientside,1)
    write(clientside,56)
    write(clientside,1)
    write(clientside,34)
    write(clientside,1)
    write(clientside,34)
    write(clientside,0)
    write(clientside,0)
    write(clientside,0)
    write(clientside,0)
    write(clientside,0)
    write(clientside,0)
end
```

The output this generates looks like this:

```
julia> roll(9884)
8104588522876597874
-8585609018870996947
57
35
35
-2674324649969450471
-7370669957356464799
6388910330871895635
-4817888634766788568
-4381550835994661230
8
-8151987627137122115
```

Where is that 8 coming from? No matter how many extra copies of `write(clientside,0)` I put in there, there is always an 8 output in the second to last line, and I have no clue where it is coming from. Any help would be great.

Comment: Instead of `write(sock,raw+1)` try `write(sock,raw)`.

Comment: @EJP The suggested modification produces the same results, with 57 and 35 replaced with 56 and 34, as one might expect. The 8 is still there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All right, the answer was posted on the julia-users group on Google groups. It turns out that 8 was the return value of roll, which was not being suppressed in REPL output.